# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection in Jboss

Tags: java, database, oracle, jboss

I am getting the following error in jboss

```
caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:296)
      ... 48 more
caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
      at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:247) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      ... 53 more
caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
      at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
      at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:150) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
      ... 58 more
```

I already checked the following things

--> Connection URl

--> DB Username and Password

--> Able to connect to same database from SQL Developer.

Please suggest me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: **Connection refused: connect**

Comment: What it means exactly

Comment: It means that you tried to open TCP connection to some server and port number. The server was reached and refused to open the connection. Either because to firewall setting or there is nothing listening or that particular port number.

Comment: I am able to create connection through noraml jdbc

Comment: Can you show us your data source configuration and piece of code where you make database call?

Comment: Are you able to connect through normal JDBC from the same client machine? JBoss is running on the same machine as SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes.It is working from same client machine